# how to fix 'file_get_content' failed to open stream

Tags: php, laravel

i'm using [cups-ipp](https://github.com/smalot/cups-ipp) to print from web project

and i got this error

> file_get_contents(./helloworld.pdf): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory

I tried to get file from storage but got the same error

```
        $builder = new Builder();

        $responseParser = new ResponseParser();

        $printerManager = new PrinterManager($builder, $client, $responseParser);
        $printer = $printerManager->findByUri('ipp://localhost:631/printers/HP_HP_ColorLaserJet_MFP_M278-M281');

        $jobManager = new JobManager($builder, $client, $responseParser);
        $filePath = '../../../storage/app/public/estimated_dates.pdf';

        $job = new Job();
        $job->setName('job create file');
        $job->setUsername('demo');
        $job->setCopies(1);
        $job->setPageRanges('1');
        $job->addFile('./helloworld.pdf');
        $job->addAttribute('media', 'A4');
        $job->addAttribute('fit-to-page', true);
        $result = $jobManager->send($printer, $job);
```

I linked storage and I'm sure that the path is correct (I also used `auto complete path plugin`)

Comment: You filename should be a string `file_get_contents("./helloworld.pdf")` try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make use of Laravel's `base_path()` helper.

`base_path()` is equal to the root of your project. So, let's, for example, you want to access `estimated_dates.pdf`. The correct solution would be:

```php
base_path('storage/app/public/estimated_dates.pdf');
```

However, you could make use of:

```php
php artisan storage:link
```

and you can access the file by: `asset('estimated_dates.pdf')`

I guess your `helloworld.pdf` is in root of the application, so:

```php
base_path('helloworld.pdf')
```

> base_path(): https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-base-path
>
> storage:link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#configuration

Comment: No problem, please mark this as a solution, it helps me.